# Corda bootcamp-cordapp throws java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for KeyPairGenerator (provider: BC) cannot be found

Tags: java, corda, java-security

I have just cloned the r3corda bootcamp-cordapp from https://github.com/corda/bootcamp-cordapp and followed the setup as mentioned in the [Bootcamp video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CKRfVlwRl2M&list=PLi1PppB3-YrVq5Qy_RM9Qidq0eh-nL11N).
The test ProjectImportedOKTest has run successfully, But when I try the StateTests it is failing with the following exception. 
I can confirm net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.KeyPairGenerator is in the classpath (eddsa-0.2.0.jar)

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for KeyPairGenerator (provider: BC) cannot be found.
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1649)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1592)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:218)
    at java.security.KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyPairGenerator.java:315)
    at net.corda.core.crypto.Crypto.generateKeyPair(Crypto.kt:674)
    at net.corda.testing.core.TestIdentity.<init>(TestUtils.kt:145)
    at net.corda.testing.core.TestIdentity.<init>(TestUtils.kt:144)
    at net.corda.testing.core.TestIdentity.<init>(TestUtils.kt)
    at bootcamp.StateTests.<init>(StateTests.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:40)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80)
    at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.KeyPairGenerator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1636)
    ... 51 more
```

Here is my StateTests.java class

```
package bootcamp;

import net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState;
import net.corda.core.identity.CordaX500Name;
import net.corda.core.identity.Party;
import net.corda.testing.core.TestIdentity;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class StateTests {
    private final Party alice = new TestIdentity(new CordaX500Name("Alice", "", "GB")).getParty();
    private final Party bob = new TestIdentity(new CordaX500Name("Bob", "", "GB")).getParty();

    @Test
    public void tokenStateHasIssuerOwnerAndAmountParamsOfCorrectTypeInConstructor() {
        new TokenState(alice, bob, 1);
    }
  //rest of the lines are commented
}
```

Here is my TokenState.java class

```
package bootcamp;

import net.corda.core.contracts.BelongsToContract;
import net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState;
import net.corda.core.identity.AbstractParty;
import net.corda.core.identity.Party;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/* Our state, defining a shared fact on the ledger.
 * See src/main/java/examples/ArtState.java for an example. */
//@BelongsToContract(TokenContract.class)
public class TokenState {

    private Party owner;
    private Party issuer;
    private int amount;

    public TokenState(Party owner, Party issuer, int amount) {
        this.issuer = issuer;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

I have ran this test in InteliJIdea (IDE Mentioned in the video is InteliJ) also, but getting the same exception.
Any help will be highly appreciated. My java version is

```
java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Java HotSpot` is not supported by Corda; read [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/getting-set-up.html) about the supported Java 8 JDK's.
I recommend going with `Oracle JDK`; which you can get [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html).

Comment: I updated the java version to java version "1.8.0_251" The hotspot JVM is Oracle implementation only. With the Sun acquisition, Oracle has two major Java Virtual Machine (JVM) implementations, the Java HotSpot VM and the Oracle JRockit JVM.
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jsp.html
So I am not sure what you meant by Java HotSpot is not supported.

Comment: Interesting, so you marked my answer as the correct one; how did my suggestion fix your problem? Can you add some details please.